# translating a sql query to active records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got the two models below. A Secondant is a role that a user can play for another user, and `secondant_id` is pointing back to a `user.id`.
What I want is to have the users for which the `current_user` plays the role of secondant. I can write the query in SQL but what would be the best way to translate that to active records?

```
class Secondant < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  before_save :find_user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :secondants
end
```

The query that gives me the result I want and that I want to convert to active record is:

```
select
    *
from
    users,
    secondants
where
    users.id = secondants.secondant_id and
    secondant_id = 2;
```

Comment: do u want to find all secondants associated with user having id=2 ?

Comment: The secondant_id = 2 would be secondant_id = current_user.id. I want to find all the users for which the current_user plays the role of secondant

Comment: Try the answer mentioned below. It will find the exact result what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query might work(untested)

```
User.select("users.*, secondants.*").joins("JOIN secondants on users.id = secondants.secondant_id").where("secondants.secondant_id = ?", 2)
```

You can't access the attributes from secondants directly on users. You will have to access it like, user["attribute_name"]

Comment: wouldn't this join on the relation that has been made in the model, i.e. user.id = secondant.user_id? I need the join on user.id = secondant.secondant_id. user.id = secondant.user_id gives me the secondants of a certain user, while I want to users of a certain secondant (if that makes sense)

Comment: Modified my answer. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Define a scope inside user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  ....
  scope :playing_as_secondant,(lambda do |user_id| 
             joins(JOIN secondants on users.id = secondants.secondant_id).where("secondants.secondant_id=?", user_id)
           end)    
  ....
end
```

Then call it whenever you want to find all users for which the current_user plays the role of secondant like this:

```
User.playing_as_secondant(current_user.id)
```

Comment: thanks, I implemented the solution I checked as an answer as a scope.